# How to listen for file system changes MAC - kFSEventStreamCreateFlagWatchRoot

Tags: cocoa, fsevents

I am listening for Directory and disk changes in a Cocoa project using `FSEvents`. I need to get events when a root folder is renamed or deleted. So, I passed `kFSEventStreamCreateFlagWatchRoot` while creating the `FSEventStream`. But even if I delete or rename the root folder I am not getting corresponding `FSEventStreamEventFlags`. Any idea what could possibly be the issue. I am listening for changes in a USB mounted device. I used both `FSEventStreamCreate` and `FSEventStreamCreateRelativeToDevice`. One thing I notices is when I try with `FSEventStreamCreate` I get the following error message while creating `FSEventStream`:

> (`CarbonCore.framework`) `FSEventStreamCreate`: `watch_all_parents`:
>   error trying to add kqueue for `fd 7` (`/Volumes/NO NAME`; Operation not supported)

But with `FSEventStreamCreateRelativeToDevice` there are no errors but still not getting `kFSEventStreamEventFlagRootChanged` in event flags. Also, while creation using `FSEventStreamCreateRelativeToDevice` apple say's if I want to listen to root path changes pass emty string `""`. But I am not able to listen to root path changes by passing empty string. But when I pass `"/"` it works. But even for `"/"` I do not get any proper `FSEventStreamEventFlags`. I am pasting the code here:

```
-(void) subscribeFileSystemChanges:(NSString*) path
{
    PRINT_FUNCTION_BEGIN;

    // if already subscribed then unsubscribe
    if (stream)
    {
        FSEventStreamStop(stream);
        FSEventStreamInvalidate(stream); /* will remove from runloop */
        FSEventStreamRelease(stream);
    }

    FSEventStreamContext cntxt = {0};
    cntxt.info = self;

    CFArrayRef pathsToWatch = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (const void**)&path, 1, NULL);


    stream = FSEventStreamCreate(NULL, &feCallback, &cntxt, 
                                 pathsToWatch, kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow, 1,
                                 kFSEventStreamCreateFlagWatchRoot );


    FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(stream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), 
                                     kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

    FSEventStreamStart(stream);


}
```

Call back function:

```
static void feCallback(ConstFSEventStreamRef streamRef, void* pClientCallBackInfo, 
                       size_t numEvents, void* pEventPaths, const    FSEventStreamEventFlags eventFlags[], 
                       const FSEventStreamEventId eventIds[]) 

{
char** ppPaths = (char**)pEventPaths; int i;

    for (i = 0; i < numEvents; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Event Flags %lu Event Id %llu", eventFlags[i], eventIds[i]); 
        NSLog(@"Path changed: %@", 
              [NSString stringWithUTF8String:ppPaths[i]]); 
    }    
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong there because I've never used FSEvents. Having said that, it sounds like what you're trying to do might be better done using DiskArbitration framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and I think I figured it out.  Apparently `kFSEventStreamCreateFlagWatchRoot` is just simply busted when using `FSEventStreamCreateRelativeToDevice`.  You have to use `FSEventStreamCreate`.  Since the former form is preferable if you're relying on historical event ids, you might need to create 2 streams.  Also, note that it appears that you don't get `kEventFlagChangedRoot` sent to you if your app isn't running, so you'll need to stat the directory when you start up.

Answer (score 3):

I think the change of the volume name is not counted as a change in the file system reported by FSEvents. Remember, the volume name itself does not really exists as a file system entry. The ones under `/Volumes` is cooked up by the OS.

It's instead covered by [Disk Arbitration](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/DiscArbitrationFramework/DiskArbitration_h/).

A short sample code follows. First, define the callback

```
#import <DiskArbitration/DiskArbitration.h>
void callBack(DADiskRef disk,CFArrayRef keys,void *context )
{
    CFDictionaryRef dict=DADiskCopyDescription(disk);
    NSString*mountPoint=[(NSDictionary*)dict objectForKey:(NSString*)kDADiskDescriptionVolumePathKey];
    NSLog(@"disk at %@:",mountPoint);
    for(NSString*key in (NSArray*)keys){
    NSLog(@"key %@ changed: %@",key,[(NSDictionary*)dict objectForKey:key]);    
    }
    CFRelease(dict);
}
```

and then install the handler like this

```
DASessionRef session=DASessionCreate(NULL);
DARegisterDiskDescriptionChangedCallback(session, NULL, NULL, callBack, NULL);
DASessionScheduleWithRunLoop(session, [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] getCFRunLoop], kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
```

Comment: HI Thanks for the answer. But I am more looking for a solution with FSEVENTS because what really bothers me is that even if I give root path "/" or any subdirectories and then delete or rename it I am not getting the proper event flags in the call back. I have pasted code in the question.

One other question, where do I get the full reference of Disk Arbiteration because I do not know which keys I should be looking or watching etc. Or inshort, where do you fins teh explanation of kDADiskDescriptionVolumePathKey or kDADiskDescriptionWatchVolumeName.

Comment: The keys can be found at http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/DiscArbitrationFramework/index.html ... Well, you know that there's a search box in the ADC website, right? Did you search the constant there? Let me think about your first question.

Comment: I copy&pasted your code, and it worked on my machine (10.6.2). Could you post your callback routine, and how you are checking the returned event flags?

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers. I have added call back function as well. i am using 10.5.8 could that be the reason?

Comment: Just to make sure: you know that `kFSEventStreamEventFlagRootChanged` is just `0x20`, right? The flags don't come in the string representation.

Comment: yea... I checked all event flags.. but I always get 0

Comment: OK, I booted into 10.5.8 and checked that it works. What I did is to watch `/tmp/boo`, and then `mv /tmp/boo /tmp/bar`. FSEvents correctly gave me the event flag `0x20`. What exactly did you do?

Comment: I am currently not at my workplace. I will try and let you know the results.

Thanks.