# .NET's FileSystemWatcher for Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, filesystem-events

.Net uses FileSystemWatcher Class for handling file and directory events. Is there any simple way i.e. built in for Objective-C?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Carbon (look at FSEvents.h), [see this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154845/how-to-listen-for-file-system-changes-mac-kfseventstreamcreateflagwatchroot).

Third parties have written Cocoa front-ends, [here’s one I haven’t used](http://aron.cedercrantz.com/CDEvents/), just as an example.